# Large dataset insert into MySQL using Node.js; quoting problems; connection pool problems

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm using node to insert records into a MySQL table using the [mysql module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql)

The working code is:

```
dataSet.forEach(async (item, index) => {
  setTimeout(db.addData, 130000, item)
})
```

I'm having trouble with a set of 455 records. The inserts fail at item 150 no matter what I do. I thought the connection pooling was supposed to prevent this?

```
Error: Too many connections
    at PromisePool.query (/PROJECTS/project1/node_modules/mysql2/promise.js:341:22)
    at Timeout.addData [as _onTimeout] (/PROJECTS/project1/db/db.js:170:42)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:571:11)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7) {
  code: 'ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR',
  errno: 1040,
  sql: undefined,
  sqlState: '',
  sqlMessage: 'Too many connections'
}
```

The function to run the insert:

```
async function addData(data) {
  const connection = mysql.createPool(DB)
  let results;
  const input = [
    data.data1,
    data.data2,
    data.data3
  ]

let SQL = `INSERT INTO destination (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (date_format(?, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s'),?,?)`

  try {
    results = await connection.promise().query(SQL, input)
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }  finally {
    return results
  }
}

module.exports = {
  addData
}
```

The database config is

```
const DB = {
  host: process.env.DBHOST,
  port: process.env.DBPORT,
  user: process.env.DBUSER,
  password: process.env.DBPW,
  database: process.env.DBTEST,
  charset: 'utf8mb4',
    waitForConnections: true,
    queueLimit: 0, // 0 = unlimited queueing
    connectionLimit: 10 // 0 = unlimited connections  
}
```

Not sure how to make this work better as a single record insert.

So then I tried building a batch insert following the example from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/shownodejs_cmd.asp?filename=demo_db_insert_multiple)

```
async function addBatchData(data) {
  const connection = mysql.createConnection(DB)
  let batch = data.map((element, index) => {
      return [`date_format('${element.data1}', '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s')`, ${element.data2}, `${element.data3.replaceAll("‘", "'").replaceAll("’", "'")}`]
  }).filter(Boolean);

  console.log(batch)
  
  let SQL = `INSERT INTO destination (col1, col2, col3) VALUES ?`

  try {
    results = await connection.promise().query(SQL, batch)
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }  finally {
    connection.end()
    return results
  }
}
```

The problem here is that the mysql module escapes ALL the single quotes with double backslash when one is proper causing the insert to fail:

```
[
  [
    "date_format('2020-04-26 19:55:00', '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s')",
    '1',
    "'Blah Blah' blah| Whatever"
  ],
  [
    "date_format('2020-04-26 21:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s')",
    '2',
    "'Other Blah' | Whatever"
  ],
  [
    "date_format('2020-04-26 21:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s')",
    '3',
    "'More Blah' | Whatever"
  ],
  [
    "date_format('2020-04-28 03:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s')",
    '4',
    "'Additional Blah' | Whatever"
  ]
]
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''date_format(\'2020-04-26 19:55:00\', \'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s\')', '1', '\'Blah Bl' at line 1
    at PromiseConnection.query (/PROJECTS/project1/node_modules/mysql2/promise.js:93:22)
    at Object.addBatchData (/PROJECTS/project1/db/db.js:139:42)
    at processData (/PROJECTS/project1/applePodcast.js:40:8)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sql: "INSERT INTO destination (col1, col2, col3) VALUES 'date_format(\\'2020-04-26 19:55:00\\', \\'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s\\')', '1', '\\'Blah Blah\\' blah | Whatever'",
  sqlState: '42000',
  sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''date_format(\\'2020-04-26 19:55:00\\', \\'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s\\')', '1', '\\'Blah Bl' at line 1"
}
```

I'm opting for flexibility to handle cases where the source data is large.

Advice and/or insights on these two issues would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE on the Pool issue**:

Apparently I did not understane how to implement that properly.

In my db module I created a function

```
async function createPool() {
  let result = mysql.createPool(DB) // DB is a global context in the module
  return result
}
```

Then in my main code, I create a pool and call the insert statement on the large dataset as described by Andrey in the accepted solution.

Works as I intended.

Now the quoting for the batch inserts is still a curious issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating new pool for each item in the dataset, and then query a connection from that pool

try to change to something like this:

```
const pool = mysql.createPool(DB);
for(const item of dataSet) {
  await insertItem(pool, item)
}
await pool.end();
```

this should fix "too many connections" problem.

Re quotation - have a look at `mysql.raw()` helper

Comment: Thanks, that resolved the pool issue. Didn't realize I was implementing it incorrectly.